# nginx url redirect from query parameter

Tags: redirect, nginx, oauth

Hi I am using oauth on a number of sub domains I control. To handle multiple sub domains that all need authentication I am using oauth2_proxy (https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy) in a Docker container. My web apps are also in docker containers. Everything works when I turn auth off.

The inspiration for the below nginx configuration where the redirect should occur came from https://github.com/18F/hub/blob/master/deploy/SSO.md

It all works for the first domain, but the second gets forwarded to the first. I don't think the redirect is configured correctly?

I think I'm close!

```
upstream dashboard.example.com {
            # dashboard
            server 172.17.0.6:9000;
}
server {
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    server_name dashboard.example.com;
    proxy_buffering off;
    error_log /proc/self/fd/2;
    access_log /proc/self/fd/1;

    location = /oauth2/start {
      proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:4180/oauth2/start?rd=%2F$server_name$arg_rd;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1;
      proxy_send_timeout 30;
      proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:4180/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_send_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
}
upstream internal.example.com {
            # wiki
            server 172.17.0.5:5000;
}
server {
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    server_name internal.example.com;
    proxy_buffering off;
    error_log /proc/self/fd/2;
    access_log /proc/self/fd/1;

    location = /oauth2/start {
      proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:4180/oauth2/start?rd=%2F$server_name$arg_rd;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1;
      proxy_send_timeout 30;
      proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:4180/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_send_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
}

server {
    server_name auth.example.com;
    location = /oauth2/callback {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:4180;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_send_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
    location = /oauth2/start {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:4180;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1;
        proxy_send_timeout 30;
        proxy_read_timeout 30;
    }
    location "~^/(?<target_host>[^/]+).example.com/(?<remaining_uri>.*)$" {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://$target_host.example.com/$remaining_uri;
    }

    location / {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it that is not working?

Comment: dashboard.example.com goes to internal.example.com. I.e they both go to 172.17.0.5:5000 even though all the headers say the correct thing (dashboard or internal)

Comment: And where is it supposed to go?

Comment: The dashboard should go to the dashboard upstream, and internal should go to the Internal upstream. Currently both going to internal upstream